# how to check user has created profile or not before taking user to the App in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to write a code where I want the user to create a profile before dive into the home page of the app.

Firstly. On the splash screen, I have to check whether the user is already login or not. If not, I have to show the user login/register screen. ( I am using firebase phone authentication in flutter) where the user will enter the phone number. here need to check that the user is a new or an existing user.

if a user is new then need to show the profile creation page. or if the user is an existing user then take him to the home screen.

please help me to write the code.

Comment: check the user object which you can access inside the auth instance, if its not null then user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Use the plugins [Firebase Auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) and [Firebase Core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core) and try this in your `build` method:

```
return FutureBuilder(
  future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Your App',
      home: snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done
          ? SplashScreen()
          : StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
              builder: (context, authSnapshot) {
                return authSnapshot.hasData ? MainView() : AuthView();
              },
            ),
    );
  },
);
```